# Access Macro dlookup error

Tags: macros, microsoft-access

[image: Screenshot 1]

---

[image: Screenshot 2]

I am trying to use DLookup in a macro to retrieve a count from a query but it will not allow me to and I am getting error 2001. I tried looking up a solution but couldn't find one. I am attaching a pic of the macro and error. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason (hard to confirm without your database): You'll get that generic error (2001) if the `DLookup` function fails under certain conditions. The IF condition worked (because the Macro Error dialog says it did), and the SetValue target field (Item) being wrong would give a different error number.

The `DLookup` function could fail with that error if for example a field, table or query name is wrong, or a data type is wrong (in the criteria expression).

You can check if the `DLookup` arguments are correct by pasting the expression in the VBA Immediate Window: Press `Alt-F11` to open the VBA IDE, and `Ctrl-G` to open the Immediate Window and paste in the following and press Enter:

`?DLookup("CountOfTreatment_ID","FacilityTreat_CountMacro_Qry","Facility_IDx=1")`

The error message when running it this way will give you a bit more information about the problem.